# Deserializing Noda Time's LocalDateTime with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, date, datetime, json.net, nodatime

I'm trying to use Json.NET to serialize some Noda Time values and having trouble. Serialization is simple enough:

```
LocalDateTime dt = ... // Assigned elsewhere
LocalDateTimePattern isoDateTimePattern = LocalDateTimePattern.GeneralIsoPattern;
JObject root = new JObject();
root.Add("time", isoDateTimePattern.Format(dt));

// Serialize other elements

using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
    serializer.Serialize(sw, root);
}
```

But deserialization is problematic. Json.NET seems to recognize the ISO-formatted date and time from above
and automatically convert it into a DateTime object, which is not what I want.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream)) {
        using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr)) {
            var root = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(jr);

            // Deserialize other elements

            var time = root.GetValue("time"); // time.Type is JTokenType.Date
            string timeStr = time.Value<string>(); // Is "01/10/2014 10:37:32"

            // Kaboom. String is not in the right format (see above comment)
            var parsedTime = isoDateTimePattern.Parse(time.Value<string>());
        }
}
```

From the fact that `timeStr` comes out as a US-formatted date and time, I would guess that `time.Value<string>()`
just calls `ToString` on some internal `DateTime` object that Json.NET has already parsed.
I could do something like

```
var cdt = time.Value<DateTime>();
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime(cdt.Year, cdt.Month, cdt.Day, cdt.Hour, cdt.Minute);
```

but that's convoluted and means Json.NET is performing unneeded conversions.

Is there any way to just get the raw string value of a JSON value?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a [NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet) available on NuGet that seems to be aimed exactly at this situation.  Here is how to set it up:

After downloading and installing the package in your solution, add the following `using` statement to your code:

```
using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet;
```

Set up your serializer like this:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
```

Then, when you deserialize, you can get a `LocalDateTime` from the `JObject` using `ToObject<LocalDateTime>(serializer)` like this:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        var root = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(jr);

        // Deserialize other elements

        var time = root.GetValue("time");
        var parsedTime = time.ToObject<LocalDateTime>(serializer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Similarly, how would you serialize? From your example, it would seem like you'd use the following, but it fails with the error "Test method LiveSerialTests.LinkTests.SerialSnapshotToJSONTest threw exception: System.ArgumentException: Object serialized to String. JObject instance expected.": `root.Add("time", JObject.FromObject(time, serializer));`

Comment: Use `JToken.FromObject(time, serializer)`, not `JObject.FromObject(time, serializer)`.  The former will convert to any kind of JToken (in this case a JValue containing a string).  The latter expects to convert into a JObject, which won't work because the converter is outputting a string.

Comment: Helpful answer. Is it possible to get the serialization in a pure `DateTimeOffset` form (2017-05-08T07:09:00+01:00)? Using `var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings().ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Serialization);` I'm getting the serialized value 2017-05-08T07:08:00Z, which is actually the same, but for compatibility with old projects I'd need to get the `DateTimeOffset` serialization format